# table data relation is not entered, encountered an error Method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection :: links does not exist

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

Ticket.php

```
Protected $table = 'tickets';

Protected $fillable = ['user_id','kategori_id','judul','prioritas_id','status_id','message','file_tambahan'];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User.php

```
protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'avatar','nama_lengkap', 'email', 'password',
];

public function getAvatar()
{
    if(!$this->avatar)
    {
        return asset('images/default.png');
    }

    return asset('images/'.$this->avatar);
}


public function ticket()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
}
```

TicketController.php

```
use App\Model\Ticket;
use App\Model\User;
use App\Model\Kategori;
use App\Model\Prioritas;
use App\Model\Status;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
  
    public function index()
    {
        $data = Ticket::with('User','Kategori','Prioritas','Status')->get();
        return view('admin.crud_ticket.index', compact('data'));
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
@foreach($data as $d)
<tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td>{{ $d->user->nama_lengkap }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
    
{{ $data->links('vendor.pagination.custom') }}
```

I keep getting the same error over and over again, I do relationships between tables

namely in the user table, category, priority, status.
and cause an error like this, if you have a solution please help me

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Helpdesk\resources\views\admin\crud_ticket\index.blade.php)

Comment: You'd need to paginate, use `->paginate()` (or `->simplePaginate()`) instead of `->get()`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Comment: Trying to get property 'nama_lengkap' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Helpdesk\resources\views\layouts\app-admin.blade.php)

Comment: works fine :), but new problems arise

Comment: Would `Ticket::with('user'...` (lowercase) work? That's how you named the relation

Comment: this happens to the master blade not the result of a relation                                                                                                                  
<span class="user-name font-weight-bolder">{{ Auth::user()->nama_lengkap }}</span>

Comment: If everything from this question works fine please post a new question with your other problem. Thx